# Why is this decay process allowed?

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum

I have been given an assignment in which I have been asked to list some quantum numbers for some given allowed processes. One of them is

$\Delta^+ \rightarrow p^+ + \pi^0$

I know that $\Delta^+$ has J value as 3/2, $p^+$ has J value as 1/2 and $\pi^0$ has J value as 0. So, clearly, the total angular momentum is not conserved. Then, why is this process allowed?

Comment: Important question: what is the orbital angular momentum of the final state?

Comment: @dmckee Is it zero?

Comment: What dmckee is getting at is that angular momentum comes in both spin and orbital flavours; you've calculated the particle spins but it's only the total angular momentum that needs to be conserved.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty  As per wikipedia, the values I have mentioned are total angular momentum.

Comment: ... of each individual particle. That can't tell you anything about how the particles are rotating about one another, though.